# Dynamically add/remove numbering for dynamic error validation list?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that uses [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), and lists the errors at the top of the page when the user clicks "Continue".

I need the errors to be in a numeric list based on each existing error, so they’d need to be generated dynamically. So for example instead of

1. [empty]
2. [empty]
3. Enter the month you were born
4. [empty]

it would be

1. Enter the month you were born

Is there a way to do this?

```
$("ul.error-menu li").each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).children('a').prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + "</span>");
});

<ul class="error-message-container error-menu">
    <li><a href="#firstName"><label class="error" for="firstName" generated="true"></label></a></li>
    <li><a href="#lastName"><label class="error" for="lastName" generated="true"></label></a></li>
    <li><a href="#dobMonth"><label class="error" for="dobMonth" generated="true"></label></a></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25812/

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `list-style-type` to `decimal`.

```
.error-message-container.error-menu li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

And yea, remove this part:

```
$("ul.error-menu li").each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).children('a').prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + "</span>");
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pr5o1qzo/**

Comment: Thank you but that didn't achieve the result I was hoping for. I need the list to reflect my initial example - there are several potential validation checks on the page. The list should only reflect the errors that are actually there, without empty spaces, and in numeric order.

Comment: @bunnycode So what does my code do then? It displays the same way right?

Comment: Your code shows an empty numeric list initially; then, if the user clicks "Continue" without filling in the fields, the list is fully populated. If the user fills in all but one field, for example, the error list has empty lines/gaps. What your code does is retains those empty gaps. What I want is just a list with only the errors, and those errors in numeric order. If there are no errors, the list does not show. If there is one error, "1. [Corresponding error]" shows. If there are two errors, 2 errors show. Etc.

Comment: Thanks! I am working on it too and will post a solution if I come up with it. I think maybe something like if length != 0 then prepend <span> (i+1), but I am not sure how to write that yet. Basically if the list item has a display:none (meaning there is no error), then skip the numeric prepend, otherwise add the numeric prepend. Struggling with the syntax though.

Comment: Ewwww... No... Not that way.

Comment: Ok. Any other suggestions on how to write it?